# Display a module on a page at any position ONLY when user logs in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

Greetings. I'm a newbie to Joomla and learning the same. I have created few modules to be displayed on the first page of my joomla website. However, I understand that they can be easily configured through the admin backend. However, I want that two of those modules, which occur in the left pane/side bar, be displayed ONLY if the user is currently logged in.

Can anyone please let me know how do I conditionally display my modules?

Ideally, I would like the left panel to be hidden without login and after successful login, the left panel modules should be visible.

Also, I would prefer following the Joomla! standard, so I don't want to change the Joomla core for this.

Kind Regards,
Verisimilitude.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck, Joomla does this natively. In the module set up in the Details section there is a setting called Access Level. Set that to registered and the module will only show up to registered users.

Assuming that your template is coded properly, the left column will collapse if there are no modules to be displayed.

Comment: Thx a lot!! Yeah, I more than in luck !